# Mixing Swift Property Observers and Inheritance

Tags: swift, inheritance, property-observer

I've been tinkering with this, and I was wondering if there is any literature on this subject, or any way of knowing what is the expected behavior.  Here is an example:

```
class A {
var paused:Bool = false {
    willSet { print("Class A willSet on paused called") }
    didSet { print("Class A didSet on paused called") }
    }
}

class B : A {
    override var paused:Bool {
        willSet { print("Class B willSet on paused called") }
        didSet { print("Class B didSet on paused called") }
    }
}

class C : B {
    override var paused:Bool {
        willSet { print("Class C willSet on paused called") }
        didSet { print("Class C didSet on paused called") }
    }
}

let testC = C()
testC.paused = true
```

When this runs I get this output:

`Class C willSet on paused called
Class B willSet on paused called
Class A willSet on paused called
Class A didSet on paused called
Class B didSet on paused called
Class C didSet on paused called`

It seems that the `willSet` is called in the usual manner of polymorphism, but `didSet` is called backwards.  This is kind of cool, but where is this behavior documented?  Is a test like this the only way of learning it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of the `didSet` calls is as expected - each child calls it's `willSet`, then calls super, then calls it's `didSet`. If you did it with literal calls to super.pause you'd have something like this, which makes the order of the `didSet` calls clear:

```
class A {
    var paused:Bool = false

    func pause(_ paused:Bool) {
        print("Class A will set paused")
        self.paused=paused
        print("Class A did set paused")
    }
}

class B : A {
    override func pause(_ paused:Bool) {
        print("Class B will set paused")
        super.pause(paused)
        print("Class B did set paused")
    }
}

class C : B {
    override func pause(_ paused:Bool) {
        print("Class C will set paused")
        super.pause(paused)
        print("Class C did set paused")
    }
}

let testC = C()
testC.pause(true)
```